# Does the sentence "They will work just fine" means that things will work "good enough" or "perfectly well"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I'm not a native speaker. A customer asked me whether a product would work for her, and I answered that it would work just fine. I was trying to say that the product would work perfectly well for her, but now I'm not sure if that was the meaning conveyed by that sentence. As far as I understand, *just fine* adds emphasis, is that correct? But I've found some dictionary and forum entries stating that the opposite was true.

Comment: You conveyed what you intended to convey. You handled the situation just fine. :)

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed *just fine*.

Unless one is trying to be sarcastic this tells them that all will be well, or as perfect as can be expected. It does not mean *adequate* or barely sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

As a native American English speaker, I think of the idiomatic adverb phrases *just fine* and *perfectly well* as near synonyms — both of which mean something like *adequately* or *satisfactorily*:

> *Why use a big word when a small one works just fine?*
> *Why use a big word when a small one works perfectly well?*
> *Why use a big word when a small one works adequately?*
> *Why use a big word when a small one works satisfactorily?*

These don't necessarily indicate that there is a shortage of excellence — only that attempts to exceed basic functionality are wasted.

I think what you might have wanted to say was:

> *This product will work perfectly for you.*

But what you said works just fine; it conveys a sense like this:

> *You could buy that product for $100, or this product that does the exact same thing for half the cost.*

<sub>Notes:

[*Just*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/just) is used in its adverb sense of *quite*.

[*Perfectly*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perfectly) is used in its sense of *quite*.

[*Fine*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fine) is used in its adverb sense of *all right*.

[*Well*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/well) is used in its adverb sense of *satisfactorily*.</sub>

Comment: As a non-native English speaker, I think just fine means it works exactly as before.

Answer (score -1):

When I hear or read the words "adequately" or "satisfactorily" or "just fine," I hear that there is room for improvement. And somehow, while "perfectly" fills the bill, "perfectly well" does not. The rule about using a big word is fine for good writing, but not perfect for indicting perfection.